# Maven returns exit 0 even though junit5 tests fail

Tags: maven, junit5

I have setup Maven to trigger some junit5 tests.

When I run:

```
mvn clean integration-test
```

I see the project build and then it also runs the tests. I see a failure in one of the unit tests.

Further down in the console output, I see:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

What am I doing wrong? My expectation is that a failed test run would stop a tool like maven and return exit code 1.

This is particularly frustrating in CI because it appears as the tests are healthy since exit code returns zero.

EDIT: Here's the POM XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.(removedforstackoverflowpost)</groupId>
    <artifactId>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</name>
    <url>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</url>
    <description>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</description>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT License</name>
            <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</name>
            <email>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</email>
            <organization>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</organization>
            <organizationUrl>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</connection>
        <developerConnection>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</developerConnection>
        <url>(removedforstackoverflowpost)</url>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-console-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- latest version (2.20.1) does not work well with JUnit5 -->
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled = true
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm running java 11

When I enter this test command:

```
mvn -ff clean integration-test
```

I get this output that ends like this:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in com.github.(removedforstackoverflowpost)

Results :

Failed tests:
  SomeTest.testSomething1:13 expected: <1> but was: <2>

Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to (removedforstackoverflowpost)/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ (removedforstackoverflowpost) ---
[INFO] Building jar: (removedforstackoverflowpost)....-0.0.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.360 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-12T00:45:03-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm a total beginner so I apologize for asking an overly simplistic question. I am new to Java/Maven/JUnit5, but I'm just looking for what I should do to have the test cause a non zero exit code. This way, my CI run (I happen to use CircleCI but that doesnt matter) would show as failed when the tests fail.

I work on a Mac and the undesired behavior that I'm describing on this ticket happens the same way on both my local Mac workstation as well as in CircleCI.

Comment: How should we know? No pom file no log output no test class etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have updated the question with additional details.

Comment: `<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>`... You should probably also merge your `maven-surefire-plugin` configurations, you're declaring two different versions which is another source of confusion.

Comment: First you must decide to work JDK 11 or 6 cause the maven.compiler.target says 6 ? If you really need to keep compatibility with 6 you have to use release configuration for maven-compiler-plugin. Furthermore you would like to use JUnit Jupiter? Yes than your minimum requirement is JDK 8 furthermore if you use maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.1 you should not define plugin dependencies and no provider is necessary.  Furthermore you have different definition of maven-surefire-plugin in your pom file..I bet that you get warnings during the build ? Have you tested on plain command line?

Answer (score 0):

Line 102 of your pom.xml is instructing Maven to ignore the failures.  Just remove `<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>` and the build will fail.